# LWC Data table overflows the parent tab div

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I have a util lwc data table component that I am calling in another LWC.

I have  main LWC placed under a tab in Account Record Detail Page like so,

[image]

This is my structure of LWC :

```
<template> <!-- this is the one placed in the tab in above screenshot -->

    <c-util-data-table></c-util-data-table>

</template>
```

here's code for `Util data table` :

```
<div class="slds-col slds-scrollable_x" > <!--style={tablewidth} -->
                        <lightning-datatable
                            key-field="Id"
                            columns={columns}
                            data={recordsToDisplay}
                            hide-checkbox-column
                            default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                            sorted-by={sortedBy}
                            onsort={onHandleSort}
                            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                            class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_top "
                            >
                    </lightning-datatable>            
                </div>
```

For now I have solved the problem by adding `style="width : 70rem"`  but as you may have guess it, it will not solve it for all the different size of screens. It will overflow the moment screen size has been changed.

How do I make the width flexible so that it doesn't overflow the parent Tab here and keep the scrollbar?

Comment: try to add css in your div
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: @ShagunSharma which div? The parent LWC or the datatable LWC?

Comment: @ShagunSharma doesnt work, I tried with both parent and child component.

Comment: If is its not working then you can try to use "slds-is-relative" in your lightning-datatable class